# Find number pattern in string

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I want to be able to find a substring within a sting but it has a distinctive pattern I am not sure how to find.

EX.

```
NSString *test1= @"Contact Names
                  67-444-322
                  Dec 21 2012
                  23941 6745 9145072 01567
                  5511 23345 614567 123456
                  Older Contacts
                  See Back Side";
```

I want to find the following pattern within the substring (these numbers but not date numbers)

```
                  23941 6745 9145072 01567
                  5511 23345 614567 123456
```

However, the format of the example string will hardly ever be the same. There will be different numbers and a different title every time other than "Contact Names", "Older Contacts" and "See Back Side". One thing that will remain constant is that the numbers I am looking for will always have 4 numbers but there could be 1 row or 10 rows.

Does anyone know how I would go about this problem? I was thinking something in terms of perhaps finding only the numbers within the string and then checking to see which numbers have 3 spaces in between.

Thanks

Comment: Will the string be formatted like you have it there? What I mean is, will the text all be on one line or on separate lines like you have it in your question?

Comment: @Lance It will be separate lines but the amount of lines can vary. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexG when you say it will be on multiple lines though, will you enter the string with the necessary `\n` escapes? As it is written up there, the string will just be a single line.

Comment: @PLPiper Sorry I just assumed the the new line (\n) character was a given. It will be a new line. Thanks

Comment: The string u r looking for will be continuous?Or there could be 4 numbers in one row...some rows with other stuff...4 more numbers..etc?I went with the continuous assumption abd i think what i did is pretty close to(if not exactly) what u r looking for.(Can easily be changed to catch the numbers if the r separated)

Comment: so you want lines with 4 components only, separated by whitespace?

Comment: The basic problem is a bad formatting of input. It seems the data is generated by an application. The problem would be easy if that application could use a tagged formatting, e.g. xml or JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use character sets to separate the string and then determine if there are 4 numbers in each component. This will only work though if the string has newline characters (`\n`) in it (as your response to Lance seems to indicate).

This is how I would go about it:

```
NSString *test1= @"Contact Names\n
              67-444-322\n
              Dec 21 2012\n
              23941 6745 9145072 01567\n
              5511 23345 614567 123456\n
              Older Contacts\n
              See Back Side";

NSArray *lines = [test1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];

// lines now contains each line in test1

for (NSString* line in lines) {

    NSArray *elements = [line componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];

    if (elements.count == 4) {
        // This line contains 4 numbers
        // convert each number string into an int if needed
    }
}
```

Sorry about the long code lines, some of Apple's selectors are a little on the long side... In any case, if elements has 4 individual (`NSString`) objects, then it is one of the lines you are seeking and you can manipulate the data as you need.

**EDIT (aside):**

On the topic of Regex (as this question contains the `regex` tag), yes you could use regular expressions, but Objective-C doesn't really have a 'nice' way of handling them... Regex is more in the domain of scripting languages and languages which have built-in support for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem is that you are assuming that the lines I require will always have elements... while this is true, there could be other words or numbers with 4 elements. The following example also has 4 elements but it is not the numbers we need. Any other suggestions? Thanks EX. David Alder 156 McleodTR

Comment: @AlexG one way you could check the validity is to examine whether each element is in fact a number by using `-intValue` or `-integerValue` and checking the result is not 0. (It will be 0 if the string is a word, or if the number itself is 0). If 0 is in fact a valid number, then you will have to combine that with an `isEqualToString:` check against `0`, '00`, `000`, and so on as long as you need to go. Alternatively you could use an `NSCharacterSet` to quickly check whether every char inside the string is in fact a number.

Comment: `NSRegularExpression` is not nice?

Comment: @ThomasW By that I mean there is Regex syntax such as `if (line =~ /C(.*)/)`. Rather you are still confined to Objective-C syntax (Swift can rectify this with custom operators). I did not mean to imply that `NSRegularExpression` was defective!

Answer (score 5):

I've tried the following and it works:

```
NSString *test1= @"Contact Names\n"
    "67-444-322\n"
    "Dec 21 2012\n"
    "23941 6745 9145072 01567\n"
    "5511 23345 614567 123456\n"
    "Older Contacts\n"
    "See Back Side";

NSString *pattern = @"(([0-9]+ ){3}+[0-9]+)(\\n(([0-9]+ ){3}+[0-9]+))*";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *results = [regex matchesInString:test1 options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [test1 length])];
if ([results count] > 0) {
    NSTextCheckingResult *result = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *match = [test1 substringWithRange:result.range];
    NSLog(@"\n%@", match); // These are your numbers
}
```

*(It also works if there is only one line of numbers.)*

Comment: You can use "\d+" instead of "[0-9]+".

Answer (score 3):

I refined my code to be more readable and to stop when it finds the string(doesnt break into lines...if you need this too tell me to add the code again or help you if having difficulty doing it)

The regular expression i used is:
-One or more numbers followed by one or more spaces (tree times all this)
-One or more numbers followed by one or more whitespaces(theses are line changes,tabs,spaces ,etc)
-I try to find this whole pattern be repeated 1 or more times

The code is

```
NSString *test1= @"Contact Names\n    67-444-322\n\nDec 21 2012\n23941 6745 9145072 01567\n5511 23345 614567 123456\nOlder Contacts\nSee Back Side\n";

//create the reg expr
NSString *pattern1 = @"(([0-9]+ +){3}[0-9]+\\s+)+";
NSRegularExpression *regex1 = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern1 options:0 error:nil];
//find matches
NSArray *results1 = [regex1 matchesInString:test1 options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [test1 length])];
if ([results1 count] > 0) {
    //if i find more series...what should i do?
    if ([results1 count] > 1) {
        NSLog(@"I found more than one matching series....what should i do?!");
        exit(111);
    }
    //find series and print
    NSTextCheckingResult *resultLocation1 = [results1 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *match1 = [test1 substringWithRange:resultLocation1.range];
    //trim leading and ending whitespaces
    match1=[match1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
            [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"the series is \n%@", match1);        
}else{
    NSLog(@"No matches found in string");
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You can use "\d+" instead of "[0-9]+".

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pcre.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char *error;
  int erroffset;
  int ovector[186];
  char re[8192]="";
  char txt[]="Dec 21 2012                   23941 6745 9145072 01567                   5511 23345 614567 123456                   Ol\";";

  char re1[]=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
  strcat(re,re1);
  char re2[]="\\d+";    // Uninteresting: int
  strcat(re,re2);
  char re3[]=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
  strcat(re,re3);
  char re4[]="\\d+";    // Uninteresting: int
  strcat(re,re4);
  char re5[]=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
  strcat(re,re5);
  char re6[]="(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 1
  strcat(re,re6);
  char re7[]="(\\s+)";  // White Space 1
  strcat(re,re7);
  char re8[]="(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 2
  strcat(re,re8);
  char re9[]="(\\s+)";  // White Space 2
  strcat(re,re9);
  char re10[]="(\\d+)"; // Integer Number 3
  strcat(re,re10);
  char re11[]="(\\s+)"; // White Space 3
  strcat(re,re11);
  char re12[]="(\\d+)"; // Integer Number 4
  strcat(re,re12);
  char re13[]="(\\s+)"; // White Space 4
  strcat(re,re13);
  char re14[]="(\\d+)"; // Integer Number 5
  strcat(re,re14);
  char re15[]="(\\s+)"; // White Space 5
  strcat(re,re15);
  strcat(re,re16);
  char re17[]="(\\s+)"; // White Space 6
   strcat(re,re17);
  char re18[]="(\\d+)"; // Integer Number 7
  strcat(re,re18);
  char re19[]=".*?";    // Non-greedy match on filler
  strcat(re,re19);
  char re20[]="(\\d+)"; // Integer Number 8
  strcat(re,re20);

  pcre *r =  pcre_compile(re, PCRE_CASELESS|PCRE_DOTALL, &error, &erroffset, NULL);
  int rc = pcre_exec(r, NULL, txt, strlen(txt), 0, 0, ovector, 186);
  if (rc>0)
 {
  char int1[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,1,int1, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",int1);
  char ws1[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,2,ws1, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",ws1);
  char int2[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,3,int2, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",int2);
  char ws2[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,4,ws2, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",ws2);
  char int3[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,5,int3, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",int3);
  char ws3[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,6,ws3, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",ws3);
  char int4[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,7,int4, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",int4);
  char ws4[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,8,ws4, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",ws4);
  char int5[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,9,int5, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",int5);
  char ws5[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,10,ws5, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",ws5);
  char int6[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,11,int6, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",int6);
  char ws6[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,12,ws6, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",ws6);
  char int7[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,13,int7, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",int7);
  char int8[1024];
  pcre_copy_substring(txt, ovector, rc,14,int8, 1024);
  printf("(%s)",int8);
  puts("\n");
  }
}
```

From next time use http://txt2re.com

and also you can make a simple string of regex. For that you can write them in only 1 char variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response but your setting char txt[] to the date and numbers which will not always be the same. The data changes, the only constant is the number of numbers per row as explained above

Comment: And have u tried this becaz it is generic regx so it might work for u

Comment: please don't use "text speech" in stack overflow answers

Answer (score 2):

Create an array with the names of all the months say monthArray.

Then split the whole string using space. Now inside a for loop check

if (four consecutive elements of the splitted array are numbers)

```
  {

 if(previous 5th, 6th and seventh element in the splited array does not belong to monthArray)//if forloop count is 7 then previous 5th means the 2nd element in the splited array
     {
       those 4 consecutive variable belongs to a row you are looking for.

      }
   }
```

//----------------------------------------------------------

```
NSArray *monthArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Dec", nil];//here you have to add the 12 monts name. Now i added only 'Dec'
NSString *test1= @"Contact Names 67-444-322 Dec 21 2012 23941 6745 9145072 01567 5511 23345 614567 123456 Older Contacts See Back Side";
NSArray *splitArray = [test1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
int count = 0;

for (int i =0; i<splitArray.count; i++) {
    if ([[[splitArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] count]==1)//checks if it is a pure integer
    {
        count ++;
    }else count= 0;

    if (count>=4) {
        if (i-4>=0) {
            if ([monthArray containsObject:[splitArray objectAtIndex:i-4]]) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (i-5>=0) {
            if ([monthArray containsObject:[splitArray objectAtIndex:i-5]]) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"myneededRow===%@ %@ %@ %@",[splitArray objectAtIndex:i-3],[splitArray objectAtIndex:i-2],[splitArray objectAtIndex:i-1],[splitArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        count = 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the code. See it will print every 4 consecutive numbers as needed.

Comment: @jjpp Thanks but I won't always have the date to use. Thats why I am struggling to figure it out. The only thing that is guaranteed is that at least 1 line will contain 4 numbers split with spaces as seen above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the quantity of the numbers never changes i.e. [5 numbers][space][4 numbers][space]...

Then you can use NSRegularExpression to set the pattern and then search a string for the pattern.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you mind providing a quick example? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try NSLingustic Tagger class.

```
NSMutableArray numbers = [NSMutableArray new];
NSString *test1= @"Contact Names
                      67-444-322
                      Dec 21 2012
                      23941 6745 9145072 01567
                      5511 23345 614567 123456
                      Older Contacts
                      See Back Side";
    NSLinguisticTaggerOptions options = NSLinguisticTaggerOmitWhitespace | NSLinguisticTaggerOmitPunctuation | NSLinguisticTaggerJoinNames;
    NSLinguisticTagger *tagger = [[NSLinguisticTagger alloc] initWithTagSchemes: [NSLinguisticTagger availableTagSchemesForLanguage:@"en"] options:options];
    tagger.string = test1;
    [tagger enumerateTagsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [test1 length]) scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameTypeOrLexicalClass options:options usingBlock:^(NSString *tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *token = [test1 substringWithRange:tokenRange];
        if(Tag == NSLinguisticTagNumber){
           [numbers addObject:token];
        }
    }];
NSLogs("All Numbers in my strings are: %@", numbers);
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil but what do you mean inside by separate your number? I wish to create a new NSString with the numbers mentioned above. Thanks

Comment: not actually tokens are the numbers you are looking for and you can saperate it in a different array says numbers

Comment: Do you mind showing the full example? I am not quite following. Thank you

Comment: please check, i have added example

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try but what is the variable "question"?

Comment: I am not getting! can you elaborate little more

Comment: 2 things: [tagger enumerateTagsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [question length]) scheme:NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameTypeOrLexicalClass options:options usingBlock:^(NSString *tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, BOOL *stop) {                              I'm getting errors on "question" and "tag"
        NSString *token = [question substringWithRange:tokenRange];
        if(Tag == NSLinguisticTagNumber){

Comment: it's a copy paste mistake! it should be your string test1. I edited mine answer :)

Comment: Thank you. I ran it with no errors and when I NSLog the NSMutableArray it is showing me it is an empty. Any other suggestions why this is happening? Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I had to add the newlines \n to your input to get mine to work but I assume you're getting the string from an API or a file so it should have the newlines there already.

```
NSString *test1= @"Contact Names\
    67-444-322\n\
    Dec 21 2012\n\
    23941 6745 9145072 01567\n\
    5511 23345 614567 123456\n\
    Older Contacts\n\
    See Back Side";

    // first, separate by new line
    NSArray* allLinedStrings =
    [test1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"^[0-9 ]+$"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:nil];
    for (NSString *line in allLinedStrings) {
        NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:line options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [line length])];
        if (matches.count) {
            NSTextCheckingResult *result = matches[0];
            NSString *match = [line substringWithRange:result.range];
            NSLog(@"match found: %@\n", match);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Lance it was not me who downvoted... giving the code a try as we speak. Will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: What was the output? Did it find no matches or did it incorrectly match other parts?